# Plotting multiple subplot animations

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am currently trying to plot four simultaneous animations in a 2x2 matplotlib matrix. My code is as follows:

```
x1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
x2 = np.random.gamma(0, 1.5, 1000)
x3 = np.random.exponential(2, 1000)
x4 = np.random.uniform(0,20, 1000)

import matplotlib.animation as animation
n = 1000
def update(curr):
# check if animation is at the last frame, and if so, stop the animation a
 if curr == n: 
    a.event_source.stop()
 plt.cla()
 fig , ax = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(5,3),sharex=False,sharey=False)
 ax[0,1].hist(x1[:curr],bins=50,alpha=0.5,normed=True)
 ax[0,0].hist(x2[:curr],bins=50,alpha=0.5,normed=True)
 ax[1,0].hist(x3[:curr],bins=50,alpha=0.5,normed=True)
 ax[1,1].hist(x4[:curr],bins=50,alpha=0.5,normed=True)

fig , ax=plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(5,3))
a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)
```

The subplots are drawn by the Artist, but the animation never fills in the histograms. No error resolves and Jupyter marks the line as complete. Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `%matplotlib notebook` before your script if you want to see the animation inside your jupyter notebook.

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html