# Looping over subplots in animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am trying to simultaneously plot four animations in matplotlib subplots. Here's the data:

```
x1 = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, 10000)
x2 = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, 10000)
x3 = np.random.exponential(2, 10000)+7
x4 = np.random.uniform(14,20, 10000)
xs=[x1,x2,x3,x4]
bins=[np.linspace(-6,1, num=21),np.linspace(0,15, num=21),np.linspace(7,20, num=21),np.linspace(14,20, num=21)]
```

Now, I tried out a few methods. This one works perfectly fine:

```
def update1(curr):
    if curr==10000:
        ani.event_source.stop()
    for ax in axs:
        ax.cla()
    axs[0].hist(xs[0][:curr], bins=bins[0], normed=True)
    axs[1].hist(xs[1][:curr], bins=bins[1], normed=True)
    axs[2].hist(xs[2][:curr], bins=bins[2], normed=True)
    axs[3].hist(xs[3][:curr], bins=bins[3], normed=True)
fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4))=plt.subplots(2,2, sharex=True)
axs=[ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4]
ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update1,interval=50)
```

But strangely enough, this one doesn't:

```
def update2(curr):
    if curr==10000:
        ani.event_source.stop()
    for i in range(len(axs)):
        axs[i].cla()
    for i in range(len(axs)):
        x=xs[i]
        axs[i].hist(x[:curr], bins=bins[i], normed=True)
fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4))=plt.subplots(2,2, sharex=True)
axs=[ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4]
ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update2,interval=50)
```

This just draws the figure and axes but does not fill in the histograms. I know that it works outside the animation (I tried). Could someone explain what's going on? I've had a look at these:

[Plotting multiple subplot animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176880/plotting-multiple-subplot-animations)

[Animation of histograms in subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910622/animation-of-histograms-in-subplot)

The first one seems to be dud and while the second one works, my initial query hasn't been resolved.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Both approaches work for me (but I had to remove `normed=True` which apparently is `undefined on 'Rectange' object` and I see the animated histograms. What python version are you using? Can you please provide the output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: While the issue has been solved, I'll leave this here for completeness. `python==3.6.2`, `matplotlib==1.19.0` and `numpy==1.13.1`. Yes, I know they're outdated but I didn't really have a choice in the matter. As for the error about `normed`, it's now deprecated and `density` is used instead. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using python `3.8-dev` with `matplotlib==3.2.2` and `numpy==1.19.0`, your code worked fine for me. Here is the entire script that worked fine for me:

```
from matplotlib import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x1 = np.random.normal(-2.5, 1, 10000)
x2 = np.random.gamma(2, 1.5, 10000)
x3 = np.random.exponential(2, 10000)+7
x4 = np.random.uniform(14,20, 10000)
xs=[x1,x2,x3,x4]
bins=[
    np.linspace(-6,1, num=21),
    np.linspace(0,15, num=21),
    np.linspace(7,20, num=21),
    np.linspace(14, 20, num=21)
]


def update1(curr):
    if curr==10000:
        ani.event_source.stop()
    for ax in axs:
        ax.cla()
    axs[0].hist(xs[0][:curr], bins=bins[0], normed=True)
    axs[1].hist(xs[1][:curr], bins=bins[1], normed=True)
    axs[2].hist(xs[2][:curr], bins=bins[2], normed=True)
    axs[3].hist(xs[3][:curr], bins=bins[3], normed=True)
fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4))=plt.subplots(2,2, sharex=True)
axs=[ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4]
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update1, interval=50)
plt.show()


def update2(curr):
    if curr==10000:
        ani.event_source.stop()
    for i in range(len(axs)):
        axs[i].cla()
    for i in range(len(axs)):
        x=xs[i]
        axs[i].hist(x[:curr], bins=bins[i], normed=True)
fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4))=plt.subplots(2,2, sharex=True)
axs=[ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4]
ani=animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update2,interval=50)
plt.show()
```

The only real difference is that I had to take out the `normed=True` parts, which were causing an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'normed'
```

I know this isn't an answer but I cannot reproduce the OP problem so I am posting something that works.

Comment: This code was actually written for a Coursera Jupyter Notebook and apparently, it ran outdated APIs `matplotlib==1.19.0` and `numpy==1.13.1`. I usually try not to update the kernel because while the code will work when manually running it, the (again) outdated autograder would throw an error. However, I tried updating them and voila, it works perfectly now. As for the error about `normed`, it's now deprecated and `density` is used instead. Yep, that's how obsolete that package was.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try it out as well as for the help.